# Add give references to "how do I ask good questions page"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, help-center

On the page https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask I would suggest to change

> Be specific
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

To:

> Be specific
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.
>
> Name books and other sources
>
> It is allowed and even a good idea to name your sources, some terms are used in a different way by different authors, if you refer to a webpage  do include a link, make your problem as easy to find as possible.
>
> Copy sources
>
> (in addition to the above) If it is a short text that you did not understand: copy the paragraph into your question. As long as your quote is short you won't be breaking copyrights (but again give the source)
>
> Link to similar questions
>
> If similar questions are asked before that don't solve your problems do link to them and do motivate why they don't answer your question , a remark like "I don't understand  of   is a good part of your question, but this should not be the whole of your question.

Motivation:

in "Search, and research" we do ask questioners to searh and research, here we just ask them to show their searching, and it makes it easier for others to locate the problem. (so that even if they are not very knowledgable about this problem they can find it)